# Cannot access locally hosted sites

Tags: iis, windows-10, hosts

I have several sites on hosted on my local iis that I cannot access all of sudden.
Error I'm getting in all browsers I have installed (Chrome, IE, Edge) is- server DNS address could not be found.

Last thing I was doing before things wend wrong- installing Web Deploy 3.5, but uninstall did not help.

I checked hosts file and bindings in iis- both are valid.

Another thing I've tried with no luck:

```
Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults : netsh winsock reset catalog
Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults : netsh int ip reset reset.log
Flush DNS resolver cache : ipconfig /flushdns
Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases : ipconfig /registerdns
Flush routing table : route /f (reboot required)
```

Ping cannot file host as well

```
Ping request could not find host XXX. Please check the name and try again.
```

At the same time htt://localhost shows Default Web site with IIS welcome page.

Answer (score 0):

This appeared to be a problem with permissions on host file- somehow those got broken